# Getting objectForKeyedSubscript unrecognized selector when parsing data in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am parsing a json file containing data to a table view with different custom cells.
In the json file I have different types of channels, looking like this:

```
[
  {
  text: "Text 1", 
  channel: "Channel1"
  },
  {
  text: "Text 2", 
  channel: "Channel2"
  },
  {
  text: "Text 3", 
  channel: "Channel3"
  }
]
```

Now, when I try to choose the 3 different custom table view cells based on what channel type it is, I get a strange error. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *post = _posts[indexPath.row];

    if (post[@"channel"][@"Channel1"]) {
        Cell1 *cell = (Cell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Configuring the cell...
        return cell;
    } else if (post[@"channel"][@"Channel2"]) {
        Cell2 *cell = (Cell2*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Configuring the cell...
        return cell;
    } else if (post[@"channel"][@"Channel3"]) {
        Cell3 *cell = (Cell3*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell3" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Configuring the cell...
        return cell;
    } else {
    }
}
```

But when I run it on the simulator it crash and gives me this error message:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa8bbf61540
2014-12-31 00:06:54.397 App[12767:2571748] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa8bbf61540'
```

I would really appreciate a solution or answer to this.

Comment: What is `__posts` and how did you parse the JSON ?

Comment: @MidhunMP _posts is what I call the dictionary for the saved texts from the json file. I parse it by using a AFJSONRequestOperation

Comment: Your line where you want to figure out the actual channel looks weird. Usually you would use the subscript channel which returns a string, and compare this to the different channel types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is incorrect,

```
if (post[@"channel"][@"Channel1"]) {
```

post[@"channel"] returns a string, "Channel1", for instance, so you can't then use another subscript ([@"Channel1"]) on it -- that's why you get that error.

It looks like what you want to do is,

```
if ([post[@"channel"] isEqualToString:@"Channel1"]) {
```